Shaky zoom with opencv python
I want to apply zoom in and out effect on a video using opencv, but as opencv doesn't come with built in zoom, I try cropping the frame to the interpolated value's width, height, x and y and than resize back the frame to the original video size, i.e. 1920 x 1080.
But when I rendered the final video, there is shakiness in the final video. I am not sure why its happening, I want a perfect smooth zoom in and out from the specific time
I built a easing function that would give interpolated value for each frame for zoom in and out :-
import cv2


video_path = 'inputTest.mp4'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)) 
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output_video.mp4', fourcc, fps, (1920, 1080))

initialZoomValue={
     'initialZoomWidth': 1920,
    'initialZoomHeight': 1080,
    'initialZoomX': 0,
    'initialZoomY': 0
}

desiredValues = {
     'zoomWidth': 1672,
     'zoomHeight': 941,
     'zoomX': 200,
     'zoomY': 0
}

def ease_out_quart(t):
    return 1 - (1 - t) ** 4

async def zoomInInterpolation(initialZoomValue, desiredZoom, start, end, index):
    t = (index - start) / (end - start)
    eased_t = ease_out_quart(t)

    interpolatedWidth = round(initialZoomValue['initialZoomWidth'] + eased_t * (desiredZoom['zoomWidth']['width'] - initialZoomValue['initialZoomWidth']), 2)
    interpolatedHeight = round(initialZoomValue['initialZoomHeight'] + eased_t * (desiredZoom['zoomHeight'] - initialZoomValue['initialZoomHeight']), 2)
    interpolatedX = round(initialZoomValue['initialZoomX'] + eased_t * (desiredZoom['zoomX'] - initialZoomValue['initialZoomX']), 2)
    interpolatedY = round(initialZoomValue['initialZoomY'] + eased_t * (desiredZoom['zoomY'] - initialZoomValue['initialZoomY']), 2)
    
    return {'interpolatedWidth': int(interpolatedWidth), 'interpolatedHeight': int(interpolatedHeight), 'interpolatedX': int(interpolatedX), 'interpolatedY': int(interpolatedY)}

def generate_frame():
        while cap.isOpened():
            code, frame = cap.read()
            if code:
                yield frame
            else:
                print("bailsdfing")
                break


for i, frame in enumerate(generate_frame()):
   if i >= 1 and i <= 60:
        interpolatedValues = zoomInInterpolation(initialZoomValue, desiredValues, 1, 60, i)
        crop = frame[interpolatedValues['interpolatedY']:(interpolatedValues['interpolatedHeight'] + interpolatedValues['interpolatedY']), interpolatedValues['interpolatedX']:(interpolatedValues['interpolatedWidth'] + interpolatedValues['interpolatedX'])]
        zoomedFrame = cv2.resize(crop,(1920, 1080), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC) 

        out.write(zoomedFrame)

# Release the video capture and close windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

But the final video I get is shaking :-
Final Video
I want the video to be perfectly zoom in and out, don't want to any shakiness

Here is graph of the interpolated values :-

This is a graph if I don't round the number too early and return the integer value only :- 
As OpenCV would only accept whole numbers for cropping, its not possible to return the values from the interpolation function in decimals

I don't see any "shakiness" in the video you posted. We need a minimal reproducible example to run your code and see the results, otherwise nobody knows what you are talking about and you're unlikely to get any help.

@stateMachine I did some changes and made the code reproducible

You round the interpolated values to 2 digits after the decimal point, but then you convert to integer just slicing off the decimal places. Consider that int(round(999.994,2)) == 999 but int(round(999.996,2)) == 1000. That means the relative difference between consecutive steps won't be consistent. Plot the results of your interpolation in a graph to better see what's happening there.

you cropped by whole pixels. that's the mistake. do not do that. use warpAffine. generate a suitable transform from primitive translation and scaling matrices. do this in the parts I described, then matrix-multiply to obtain the composed transform. don't try to formulate the entire matrix at once. give this a try. let me know how you're doing.

@ChristophRackwitz Thank you for the comment, I honestly don't understand what you said, this sounds too complex, can you please if possible show a small example?

@DanMašek You are right, I posted a graph in my original question and I could see that the values are not changing smoothly, there is some change

@DanMašek When I removed the round and conversion to integer code, it would return a decimal value, and we can't actually crop frame with values in decimal

Yep, that's why a different approach is needed, as Christoph suggests.

@DanMašek New approach needed for only the interpolated return values or the entire zoom in and out logic?

@ChristophRackwitz Any help please

I haven't looked at the interpolation method in detail. Here's an example how to do zooming using an affine transform. Note that scaling happens around origin, so we need to add some translation before/after to make it zoom around the center of the image. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Image_transformation

answer coming right up... videos: https://imgur.com/a/mDfrpre

First, let's look at why your approach jitters. Then I'll show you an alternative that doesn't jitter.
In your approach, you zoom by first cropping the image, and then resizing it. That cropping only happens by whole pixel rows/columns, not in finer steps. You saw that especially well near the end of the ease, where the image is zoomed very finely. The cropped image would change width/height by less than a pixel per frame, so it only changes every couple of frames. The jerkiness would worsen the closer you zoom because then a pixel becomes larger.
Instead of cropping like this, calculate and apply a transform matrix for every frame. This involves warpAffine() or warpPerspective(). Considering the source image to be a texture, these functions run over every destination pixel, use the transform matrix to calculate the point in the source image, then sample that in the source image, with some interpolation mode.
The compound transform is calculated from three primitive transforms:

move a particular point (the "anchor") of the image to the origin
scale around origin (the anchor)
move to where it should be in the video frame

In the code, I build this transform in this sequence. You could also write that in a single expression as T = translate2(*+zoom_center) @ scale2(s=z) @ translate2(*-anchor). Yes, the operations expressed by these matrices are applied from right to left.
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from tqdm import tqdm # remove that if you don't like it

# Those two functions generate simple translation and scaling matrices:

def translate2(tx=0, ty=0):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2, 2] = [tx, ty]
    return T

def scale2(s=1, sx=1, sy=1):
    T = np.diag([s*sx, s*sy, 1])
    return T

# you know this one already

def ease_out_quart(alpha):
    return 1 - (1 - alpha) ** 4

# some constants to describe the zoom

im = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("starry_night.jpg"))
(imheight, imwidth) = im.shape[:2]

(output_width, output_height) = (1280, 720)

fps = 60
duration = 5.0 # secs

# "anchor": somewhere in the image
anchor = np.array([ (imwidth-1) * 0.75, (imheight-1) * 0.75 ])
# position: somewhere in the frame
zoom_center = np.array([ (output_width-1) * 0.75, (output_height-1) * 0.75 ])

zoom_t_start, zoom_t_end = 1.0, 4.0
zoom_z_start, zoom_z_end = 1.0, 10.0

# calculates the matrix:

def calculate_transform(timestamp):
    alpha = (timestamp - zoom_t_start) / (zoom_t_end - zoom_t_start)
    alpha = np.clip(alpha, 0, 1)
    alpha = ease_out_quart(alpha)
    z = zoom_z_start + alpha * (zoom_z_end - zoom_z_start)

    T = translate2(*-anchor)
    T = scale2(s=z) @ T
    T = translate2(*+zoom_center) @ T

    return T

# applies the matrix:

def animation_callback(timestamp, canvas):
    T = calculate_transform(timestamp)
    cv.warpPerspective(
        src=im,
        M=T,
        dsize=(output_width, output_height),
        dst=canvas, # drawing over the same buffer repeatedly
        flags=cv.INTER_LANCZOS4, # or INTER_LINEAR, INTER_NEAREST, ...
    )

# generate the video

writer = cv.VideoWriter(
    filename="output.avi",  # AVI container: OpenCV built-in
    fourcc=cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), # MJPEG codec: OpenCV built-in
    fps=fps,
    frameSize=(output_width, output_height),
    isColor=True
)
assert writer.isOpened()

canvas = np.zeros((output_height, output_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

timestamps = np.arange(0, duration * fps) / fps

try:
    for timestamp in tqdm(timestamps):
        animation_callback(timestamp, canvas)

        writer.write(canvas)

        cv.imshow("frame", canvas)

        key = cv.waitKey(1)
        if key in (13, 27): break

finally:
    cv.destroyWindow("frame")
    writer.release()
    print("done")

Here are several result videos.
https://imgur.com/a/mDfrpre
One of them is a very close zoom with nearest neighbor interpolation, so you can see the pixels clearly. As you can see, the image isn't "cropped" to whole pixels. You can see pieces of pixels at the edges.
For fun I also made one video with multiple animation segments (pause, in, pause, out, pause). That merely needs some logic in calculate_transform to figure out what time segment you're in.
zoom_keyframes = [ # (time, zoom)
    (0.0, 15.0),
    (1.0, 15.0),
    (2.0, 16.0),
    (3.0, 16.0),
    (4.0, 15.0),
    (5.0, 15.0),
]

def calculate_transform(timestamp):
    i0 = i1 = 0
    for i, (tq, _) in enumerate(zoom_keyframes):
        if tq <= timestamp:
            i0 = i
        if timestamp <= tq:
            i1 = i
            break

    if i1 == i0: i1 = i0 + 1

    # print(f"i0 {i0}, i1 {i1}")

    zoom_ta, zoom_za = zoom_keyframes[i0]
    zoom_tb, zoom_zb = zoom_keyframes[i1]

    alpha = (timestamp - zoom_ta) / (zoom_tb - zoom_ta)
    alpha = np.clip(alpha, 0, 1)
    alpha = ease_out_quart(alpha)
    z = zoom_za + alpha * (zoom_zb - zoom_za)

    T = translate2(*-anchor)
    T = scale2(s=z) @ T
    T = translate2(*+zoom_center) @ T

    return T


Thank you so much Chris for the answer, I really appreciate your help and the time you gave for the solution.
Just a quick question, instead of zooming in on the center, can I zoom in on specific points? like x and y coordinate :- 10, 40 ?

yes, easily. the code already has such coordinates defined. imagine a pin piercing through the image and the video. zoom_center is the location of the pin in the frame, anchor is the location of the pin in the image. you can change or even animate those.

if you need to do this to a video source instead of a still image, I wouldn't recommend OpenCV's VideoWriter, but PyAV instead. That will give you the "presentation timestamps" of the source video frames.

Thank you so much for the solution again, I am playing around with the code you shared in order to fit in my current project. I actually need the ability to capture video instead of a still image there and be able to write a mp4 video of it
